# calculating the number of user receving a push notification

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

In the startup I'm currently working, we have developed a push server that enables the user to receive push notification when new content uploaded in our database.

Our system currently stores how many push are send and through Google analytics we can see how many people interact with the push notification, yet we would like to know how many people in total receive the push notification.

How can we count how many devices recevie the push? Which method could we use? As an example users unistall the app but we still have them stored on our database, or users may opt-out from the push through system settings (both ios and android)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using same analytics by which you are able to identify how many people interacted with push using analytics. you will have to call your analytics function for pushRecieved in broadCastReciever for your GCM implementation.